# Get data multiple data from firebase for javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How i can get all data from hotel to cant print the data to console, to be able to print in this way the data

"nombre, rfc, infGen,ubicacion"

[image: My database]

Comment: The answer to your question is in the documentation for firebase. firebase.database().ref('Hotel').once('value').then(function(snapshot){}, function(error){})

Comment: i read the documentation, but i cannot undertand how get list of data, and manage the results

Comment: in the first function, the variable snapshot is your firebase query response. snapshot.val() would give you the object containing the data you are after

Comment: thanks, i find the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

foreach is the operation that need, this get data one by one

```
var query = firebase.database().ref("Hotel/"+usuario.uid);
        query.once("value")
          .then(function(snapshot) {
            snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
              var hrfc = childSnapshot.val().RFC;
              var hnombre = childSnapshot.val().nombre;
              var hinfo = childSnapshot.val().infoGen;
              var hubic = childSnapshot.val().ubicacion;


          });
        });
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [Firebase REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/) if the realtime reference syntax is throwing you off. Using an AJAX library (I will use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for the example), you can easily read data from your database.

Below are some examples on how to read data from Firebase.

```
// This first call will return the root of your database
// By appending the url with '.json', the response will be JSON
axios('https://**your-database-here**.firebaseio.com/.json')
.then(response => {
  // Using .then to access the resolved data from the promise
  // "response" itself is an object, but our data is assigned to the data property
  console.log(response.data);
});

// This call will return a single collection, such as the Hotel collection. 
// Be aware that firebase does not return array, but instead returns an object of key - value pairs
axios('https://**your-database-here**.firebaseio.com/Hotel.json')
.then(response => {
  console.log(response.data);

  var hotel = response.data; // Again, just wait the actual data
  // Will need to loop over object to get nested data here
});

<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```